# Is there a way to use qtawesome with enaml?

Tags: enaml

Is there a way to use Icons from qtawesome (https://github.com/spyder-ide/qtawesome/) within enaml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment there is no clean way to do this, however you can use the following workaround:

```
from  enaml.widgets.api import Window, PushButton, Container
from enaml.icon import Icon

from qtawesome import icon as qicon

enamldef Main(Window):

    Container:

        PushButton:
            text = "Open"
            icon = Icon(_tkdata=qicon('fa.folder-open'))
```